# node-menu dynamic menu item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [node-menu 1.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-menu) and I would like to have dynamic menu items based on certain conditions, something like this:

```
menu.addDelimiter('-', 40, '')

if(condition){
   .addItem('Conditional Item 1', conditional_function)
  } else {
    .addItem('Conditional Item 2', conditional_function_2)
 }

.customHeader(Header)
.disableDefaultHeader()
.customPrompt(function() {
    process.stdout.write("\nEnter selection:\n");
})
.disableDefaultPrompt()

.start();
```

I am not even sure how to approach it. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Actually the problem is a bit more complicated, I have an event that will change based on user input, like this:

```
isListening()
  .then(value -> {
    menu
      .additem('Item 1', item1)
      .additem('Item 2', item2)
      .start();
   })
.catch(error => {
       menu
      .additem('Item 3', item3)
      .start();
});
```

`function item3` will change `isListening()` to `true` starting the other menu.

Answer (score 0):

Write condition outside addItem and use the value after resolving condition,

```
   var conditionVal, conditionFunc

    if(condition){
      conditionVal = 'Conditional Item 1';
      conditionFunc = conditional_function
      } else {
       conditionVal = 'Conditional Item 2';
       conditionFunc = conditional_function_2
     }

    menu.addDelimiter('-', 40, '')
    .addItem(
      conditionVal,
      conditionFunc
    )
```

Comment: please see the updated question, the problem is a bit more involved. thanks!